# solve O(n log n) dynamic programming question for max total length of some intervals

Tags: python, algorithm, math, data-structures, dynamic-programming

`N` intervals is given. `A_i= [S_i, F_i]` means start and finishing time of each interval. Start and finishing time of all interval is distinct. we wan to `maximize total length` of selected intervals that noon-overlap with each others.

Question 1) **What is DP logic of this problem using O(n log n) time?**

Question 2) is it equal to weighting interval schedule such that weight becomes length of interval?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of `maximize total length` mentioned in your question.
Actually classic interval scheduling algorithms works for `maximum count` not `maximum length`
so none of the options always works

you need to sort A_i increasing by F_i and then follow this dynamic approach from i =0 to n in each step calculate the max sum interval with A_0 to A_i if you want to calculate A-i+1 there's 2 situations A_i+1 doesn't have overlap with max sum found in prev step then add it to sum else if there's overlap then find all A_i who has overlap with A-i+1 with O(lgn) (binary search) and remove them and then compare f(k)+A_i+1 with A_i and decide to keep A_i+1 or not

Comment: please clean comments